# Store 3D objects? (Java)

Tags: java, 3d, java-3d, alice

I am making a program such as [Alice from Carnegie Melon University](http://www.alice.org/) using JAVA.

I am *not* asking about Alice! What I *really* want to know is **HOW DO I Store `3D Graphics`**?

I can't seem to find a very efficient way to store complicated 3D objects and figures! I need this for 3D object libraries. I have extracted all the files from `alice.JAR` and decompiled them to `*.JAVA`. I have studied them and I don't get it. I *think* Alice stores them in `*.XML`. Am I correct? If so, how are the `*.XML` files so small? Is there any better way to store 3D Graphics?

I am <strike>kind of</strike> ***really*** confused!?!

Can *anybody* **please** help me?

Any answers would be ***greatly*** appreciated! :)

Comment: If it really matters, my OS is Windows XP Service Pack 2.

Comment: You may want to look at [X3D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X3D) or maybe [VRML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VRML)

Comment: Why don't you post some source which you think may help. Otherwise, you are asking all of us to decompile Alice just to look around

Comment: Thank you MacroS! Peaches491, There is _SO MUCH_ code in Alice, and I'm not a JAVA expert, I don't know what code to show! I'm just asking if you know how to store super-complex 3D Graphics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically You have a list points, and a list of vertices.

```
List points = new ArrayList<Point3D>();

List verts = new ArrayList<Vertex3D>();
```

You should encapsulate this data into an object and write it out you could do something like this

NOTE not adding all the constructors / public methods

```
CLass Model3D {

    List points = new ArrayList<Point3D>();
    List verts = new ArrayList<Vertex3D>();
}

Model3D m = new Model3D();

ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutpuStream(new FileOutputStream( new File('./3d-file-otuput') ) );
oos.write(m);
```

Comment: ***Thank you***!!! From what I understand (I'm _not_ an expert on `JAVA`) You just have to store the coordinates of the points in some type of file?

Comment: Yea you need to store Points, Vertices, Texture Coord (U,V), and color information